# Pretty Error URLs in MVC3 for 404, 500 Etc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, http-status-code-404

My current error handling URLs look rather ugly:

```
http://localhost:65089/Error/NotFound?aspxerrorpath=/Foo
```

Would rather have something like this:

```
http://localhost:65089/Error/NotFound
```

**Web Config Code**

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Unknown">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
    </customErrors>
```

**Error Controller**

```
  public class ErrorController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Error/

        public ActionResult Unknown()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult NotFound()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may be of some interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc/2577095#2577095

Answer (score 0):

You can modify Application_Error method in your Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
            if(ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode()==404)
            {
                Response.Redirect("/Error/NotFound");
            }
        }
```